# Adding a class to top level element if a string is nested deep within

Tags: jquery

I have divs inside divs. About 3 or 4 levels deep I have a div that contains a P tag which contains a span tag. I need to add an additional class to a div higher up with an already existing class and based upon wether or not my nested span contains a specific string.

Here is my html code: [pastebin.com link](http://pastebin.com/LrJNfntH)

I need to check my nested span element to see if it contains the string 'october' and if so add an additional class of "October" to the top div that already has a class of 'event-data'.

Answer (score 0):

If the span that contains your string is `el`, then you could set the parent class like this:

```
$(el).parents(".event_data").last().addClass("October")
```

The key here is that `.parents(sel)` will return all parents that match a given selector and they are returned in order from closest to furthest up the parent chain.  Then, `.last()` picks the last one (the furthest up the parent chain) and then `addClass()` adds the desired class to the remaining parent object.

If you also need help finding the span and testing for your text, then you need to provide more guidance on how you identify the span that you want to test for the text.

---

Your description of where to look for the text is still a bit hazy and non-specific, but here's one way to do the whole thing:

```
$('p[id^="event_date-"]:contains(October)')
    .parents(".event_data").last().addClass("October");​
```

And, you can see it work here on your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Pp8gw/

Explanation:

- Finds `p` tags with an id that starts with `"event_date-"`
- Within that `p` tag, it finds text `"October"`
- Find all ancestors that have a class of `"event_data"`
- Get the furthest ancestor
- Add the class `"October"` to that ancestor

Comment: I dont understand what (el) is I have never come across this.

Comment: @BrettGolding - `el` is a DOM reference to the span that contains your text.  As I said in my answer, if you need help finding the span, then you need to give us some guidance for how to figure out which span to look for the text in.  You have a number of different spans and I assume you don't want to look in just any span in your page.

Comment: the span has a class of section-title

Comment: @BrettGolding - I added a new part to my answer that both finds the text October and adds the class.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I didn't forget anything

```
var span=$("p>span");

for(var i=0;i<span.length;i++) {
    if(span[i].text().indexOf("october") >= 0)) {
        span[i].parents("div.event-data").addClass("October");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The bottom one of your examples.